# Site to Site VPN Tunnels

Tags: vpn, firewall, routing, site-to-site-vpn

This is more of a theoritcal question then a problem. With regards to Site to Site VPN links, let's for the sake of the question say we have two `Sonicwall Firewalls`.

`Site A` and `Site B`

`SonicwallA` and `SonicwallB` respectively to the sites mentioned above.

1). Now if I was to create a Site to Site VPN on `SonicwallA at SiteA` and set the Primary Gateway to the IP of `Sonicwall B at SiteB` but didn't configure anything on SonicwallB - what connectivity would I achieve?

2). Next I would go and configure a Site-to-Site Link on SonicwallB and set Primary Gateway for the VPN to IP of SonicwallA. What connectivity would I achieve then with both active?

The reason I ask this is because a Site-to-Site VPN only establishes one tunnel, but how is that possible with two Firewalls connecting to each other via two totally seperate Site-to-Site VPN configurations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. No connectivity whatsoever. Imagine the security disaster that the world would be if anyone could set up a site-to-site VPN by configuring only the device on *their* end.
2. Assuming that the rest of the configuration is correct and complete, you have a tunnel between SiteA and SiteB.

They are not two totally separate site-to-site VPN configurations. Each device needs to be configured to communicate with the other in order to establish a single connection.